# ConvertFrom-SecureString trims string when using SecureKey

Tags: powershell, encryption

I found out yesterday that when I am converting a secure string using ConvertFrom-SecureString in combination with -SecureKey parameter my string/password is being always trimmed to 32 characters, which is of course not desirable. My SecureKey has 16 characters if it helps).

Steps to reproduce:

```
$stringToSecure = 'ThisIsMySuperStrongVeryLongPassword'

$ConvertToSecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $stringToSecure -AsPlainText -Force
$EncryptSecureStringWithSK = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $ConvertToSecureString -SecureKey $SecureKey
$EncryptSecureStringWithoutSK = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $ConvertToSecureString

### With SecureKey
$SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $EncryptSecureStringWithSK -SecureKey $SecureKey
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ('dummy@cat.com', ($SecureStringPassword))
$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
ThisIsMySuperStrongVeryLongPassw

### Without SecureKey
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ('dummy@cat.com', ($EncryptSecureStringWithoutSK | ConvertTo-SecureString))
$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
ThisIsMySuperStrongVeryLongPassword
```

I am using a base64 AES key, which I then convert to bytes array of length 32 and then secure the SecureKey using that AES key bytes array

```
$SecureKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $GetSecureKey -Key $AESKey
```

Would someone please explain this behavior and if possible to fix it so the password won't be trimmed using SecureKey parameter?

Comment: I'm unable to produce this in both PowerShell 5.1 and 7.1 with `$SecureKey = '0123456789ABCDEF' |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlaintext -Force`. Can you show how you construct your `$SecureKey` value?

Comment: I am using a base64 AES key, which I then convert to bytes array of length 32 and then secure the SecureKey using that AES key bytes array

$SecureKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $GetSecureKey -Key $AESKey

Comment: Please [update your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69553941/edit) with the key generation/convert code